# Making CSS changes for multiple pages: combining code?

Tags: css, wordpress

On my Wordpress website, I want to make featured image smaller on only some pages.

So I can repeat the code for each page that I want to change. This works, but it's a little messy.

```css
.page-id-8 .page-header.has-featured-image {
    padding: 2rem 3.75rem;
}

.page-id-1018 .page-header.has-featured-image {
    padding: 2rem 3.75rem;
}
```

How could I combine this code? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't help that both padding settings are the same, please provide a more representative example.

Comment: why not just give the images that need that padding an extra class?

Comment: You can combine them with a comma

Comment: `.page-id-8 .page-header.has-featured-image, .page-id-1018 .page-header.has-featured-image {...}` if you want to make that work on every page, remove the `.page-id-xxx` and use only `.page-header.has-featured-image{...}`

Comment: Thanks @toffler, that's what I meant. It works!

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-id-8 .page-header.has-featured-image,
.page-id-1018 .page-header.has-featured-image {
    padding: 2rem 3.75rem;
}
```

Are these generated classes/code?

you can alse use

```
.page-header.has-featured-image{
padding: 2rem 3.75rem;
}
```